# Playing iPod Library songs using CocosDenshion

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmediapickercontroller

I am trying to let the user select a song from the iPod Library. After getting the song URL from that, I am trying to play it using the `CocosDenshion` library but I am not getting any sound.

Here's the code sample of `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`:

```
#pragma mark MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
  didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaItemCollection count] < 1) {
        return;
    }
    [song release];
    song = [[[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0] retain];


    NSURL *itemURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    fileURL = [itemURL absoluteString];

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:fileURL];
}
```

and here's the handler for the button that plays the sound.

```
- (IBAction)playSong {

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:fileURL pitch:1.0f pan:0.0f gain:1.0f];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong. I need to be able to change the pitch of the selected song. That is why I am using CocosDenshion library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the URL returned by `[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]` in the debugger. It is not a standard file system URL but a custom URL that points into the asset library so it is no wonder CocosDenshion can't open it.

You will need to use AV Foundation (probably `AVAudioPlayer`) to play the song. Or use AV Foundation to first convert the song into a "real" file and then play it back with Cocos Denshion but that is probably much more complicated than the first option.

The documentation for `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` clearly says so, too:

> Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported.

Comment: Update: AVPlayer can play an iPod library url. The AVAudioPlayer cannot play from an iPod library url.